# How to autoload files using zend framework like namespaces fashion

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload

I am developing a new application from scratch and I need to autoload files recursively. 
However, I need to use namespace like Zend Framework.

For example, `LibraryName_Http_Request` will load `LibraryName/Http/Request.php` file.
Whatsoever I've tried, I can only use `LibraryName_Http_Request` class if I name the file `LibraryName_Http_Request.php`.

I can't figure out how to change my code so that i can load class files in the same Zend fashion...

Here is my code:

```
class Autoloader
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        spl_autoload_register( array( $this, 'autoload' ) );
    }

    public function autoload( $class )
    {
        $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( LIBRARY_PATH );

        foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $iterator ) as $file=>$meta ) {

            if( ( $class . '.php' ) === $meta->getFileName() ) {

                if( file_exists( $file ) ) {
                    require_once $file;
                }
                break;
            }
        }        

        unset( $iterator, $file );
    }

}
```

Comment: At some point you'll need to replace underscores with the directory separator.

Comment: Why you don't want to use `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` and register namespaces you require ?

Comment: b.b3rn4rd - I can't use any other Library in the project! 
@Mike B - I tried a lot of things to replace the file, but none worked!

Comment: You could use the autoloader system shipped with Composer, is light and you can reduce it two a couple of files for your needs

Comment: I have updated my answer. Does it now to your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [**PSR-0**](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) which does what you want. You can find a link to [PSR-0 loader implementation](https://gist.github.com/221634) at the end of the recommendation.

---

**Update:** Since you are using PHP 5.2, the above loader doesn't fully fit to your needs. Here is a simple autoloader I wrote based on PSR-0 without namespace support:

```
class SimpleClassLoader
{
    /**
     * Installs this class loader on the SPL autoload stack.
     */
    public function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'));
    }

    /**
     * Uninstalls this class loader from the SPL autoloader stack.
     */
    public function unregister()
    {
        spl_autoload_unregister(array($this, 'loadClass'));
    }

    /**
     * Loads the given class or interface.
     *
     * @param string $className The name of the class to load.
     * @return void
     */
    public function loadClass($className)
    {
        require str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
    }
}
```

Then register the loader:

```
$loader = new SimpleClassLoader();
$loader->register();
```

Now referencing `LibraryName_Http_Request` will include `LibraryName/Http/Request.php`.

Comment: I deleted my answer - this one is better and more up with new recommendations.

Comment: PSR-0 is a load of nonsense. http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/11/on-psr-0-being-included-in-phps-core.html

Comment: @GordonM I disagree with you. I would be happy to read **your opinion**, not _Anthony Ferrara_'s one. Yes, PSR-0 is not perfect but when coupled with a classmap autoloader you can load almost every class from every PHP project. If you don't like my answer feel free to post yours. Tell me if I'm wrong but (your framework) reefknot's autoloader is PSR-0 compliant right?

Comment: @Florent The organization of classes in the file structure is PSR-0-like (and it probably would work fine with a PSR-0 loader) but the way classes are organized under PSR-0 isn't the problem, it's a sensible schema.  The problem is that it tries to do too much and doesn't handle edge cases properly (as Anthony stated), and it certainly shouldn't error out because it couldn't load the class!  My autoloader isn't set up to handle _ namespacing by default at all (though you could configure an instance of it to handle it).

Comment: @Florent I am not using PHP 5.3... and stuck in PHP 5.2 that's why I've created the class posted above. I already use the PSR-0 loader implementation but it can't help me now!

Comment: Now autoloader is **PHP 5.2 compatible**.